# iOS: PageViewController with Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iOS app development and I am attempting to create use a pageviewcontroller to have a left and right scroll-able menu with clickable buttons. I have a top and bottom section
which I do not want to scroll. The scrollable menu is in the middle. I followed [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) tutorial and was able to get the desired effect but I am unable to do anything with the buttons inside each of the view controllers. I am guessing that this is possibly due this chunk of code from the linked tutorial:

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
 return [self.newColoredViewController("Green"),
    self.newColoredViewController("Red"),
    self.newColoredViewController("Blue")] }()
```

`private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)ViewController")
}`

Is it creating a viewcontroller class on the fly which I am unable to access? How do I go about controlling the buttons on each viewcontroller.

Here is a basic drawing of the app.

[App Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix4Ou.png)

There is a top and bottom section, with the horizontal scrollable menu in the middle. I am developing an Android and iPhone version. I currently have the Android version finished and need the iPhone to look as close to the Android as possible.

Comment: where exactly are you calling themethod : private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController  ?

Comment: From the pageviewcontroller class.

Comment: do you want those button on each page or out that page which will be static?

Comment: I want buttons on each page. In the app I have 9 buttons on the first page and 2 on the next for a total of 11 buttons.

Comment: Am I only able to put static items inside pageviewcontrollers?